# How to share mongoose models with multiple microservices

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, microservices

I've a User model which looks like:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I'm trying to share this model with multiple microservices, but how do i share this? Should i make a database service exposed over http or should i manually make models in each server and use it that way, or is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's dangerous to share schemas across microservices because they could become very coupled, or at least not like that. It's normal that microservices use data from each other, but models should not be fully imported in another microservice. Instead, the dependent microservices should use a subset, a local representation of the remote model. For this you should use an [Anti-corruption layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer). This ACL would receive as input remote models and produce as output a local, immutable/readonly representation of that model. The ACL lives at the outer boundary of the microservice, i.e. where the remote calls are made.

Also, sharing `*schema.js` files across microservices would force you to use JavaScript/NodeJS in all the other microservices, which is not good. Each microservice should use whatever programming language is best suited for it.

> Should i make a database service exposed over http

The database is private to the owning microservice. It should not be exposed.